# How does wordpress add 'style' attribute to <a> element

Tags: filters

In my post the html code is like this:

```
<p><a href="http://mysite.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/mypic.jpg"><img class=" wp-image-124 aligncenter" alt="xxxx" src="http://mysite.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/mypic.jpg" /></a></p>
```

after I published this post, the html code will change to :

```
<p><a href="http://mysite.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/mypic.jpg" style="display: block; width: 600px; height: 400px;"><img class=" wp-image-124 aligncenter" alt="xxxx" src="http://mysite.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/mypic.jpg" /></a></p>
```

it seems like wordpress or some plugin add `style="display: block; width: 600px; height: 400px;"` to my post,

my question is how does this happen? what part of code did this? is it possible to stop this?

Thank you!

Comment: Switch themes, disable plugins. I'd bet on the theme. If you isolate it we might be able to stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress of course does nothing so it might be a plugin do this, or a custom theme function.

How does this happen? The plugin may use [the_content filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) to find all "" element and inject content. Or it can be a visualize text editor with JavaScript code that modify content itself without applying a filter.

It's hard to give a correct answer for this kind of issue. If I were you, I will do these steps to find *the plugin* create that shit:

- Switch to another theme and see if problem is stil there.
- If yes, try to manually search in the theme file.
- If not, then problem is plugin, not theme. Try to disable plugin one by one to find out which plugin is the root cause. Then disable it.
- You should get a local copy of site and work with it because sometimes disable a plugin can affect the site working properly.

If for some reason, you cannot do that, then try do this:

- Try to disable JavaScript completely. You will get a weird WordPress admin panel. However you are still be able to add a new post. Try to see if that piece of code did't get inject. If yes, then try to do below step.
- Do a search to find out that exactly string in which file.
- Do a search to find out similar string in whcih file: for example try to find "style=" string in *.php file only. You just need to search on wp-contents folder

Once you found out the plugin, just disable it. DON'T ever think of modifying it. Just disable and remove it. A plugin which is injecting that code must be maintain by a bad developer.